# Firebase init - Error: Unexpected rules format .rules

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I'm writing a Vue2 App using Firebase and Firestore to manage my data. Now I want to host the Application on Firebase. The firebase console told me to "firebase init" my project (done), then "firebase deploy" to deploy it.
My problem is, when I type "firebase deploy" it just crashes and returns an error:

[image: error]

I coldn't find a solution online so I hope someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I didn't build my npm project before hosting. After running `npm run build` I was able to deploy the app with `firebase deploy --only hosting`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `firebase.json` configuration file points to a file with invalid [database security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules). Since `firebase deploy` tries to deploy everything you've [configured](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deployment) in your `firebase.json` file, this causes the deployment to fail.

The simplest way to avoid the problem is to tell the Firebase CLI to only deploy to Firebase Hosting with:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

---

The better fix is probably to figure out why the file contains illegal contents, and either fix that or remove it altogether (if you're not using the database, or don't want to use the CLI to deploy the rules)/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't changed anything in the rules. Therefore I'm wondering whats wrong or why Firebase can not read the .rules format, because the files were written by the firebase cli itself. Your suggested command only deploys a blank page on localhost:5000. :/

Comment: It's impossible to say what's wrong with the rules without seeing the rules file and the `firebase.json` config, hence the mentioned workaround to allow you to get the deploys working quickly.